# Being notified via email of errors in cron jobs

Tags: email, cron

You would like to be notified via email of errors occurring while executing cron jobs.

I use CentOS and the file /etc/crontab for the configuration.

The first step I have done is:

```
MAILTO=my_email_address
```

and then I have appended this to each crontab entry:

```
2>/dev/null
```

That means this

```
24 4 * * * root /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

becomes:

```
24 4 * * * root /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org 2>/dev/null
```

In that way I should suppress the normal output and let error messages be sent.

I would like to know if you think what I have done is right and whether that has got any pitfall.

Thanks, 
Dan

Comment: Based on the other users' feedback the correct way is: 24 4 * * * root /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org > /dev/null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I think you've done the exact reverse of what you wanted; you've suppressed the error messages (by sending STDERR to /dev/null) and will get only the normal output.

Try

```
24 4 * * * root /usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org > /dev/null
```

Better still, run ntpd; it's a much better way of keeping your clocks in sync than brute-force resetting them once a day.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC cron emails the **output** of the command, so if you suppress errors (by throwing them at */dev/null*) you'll receive ONLY command output and not errors. I found a nice script: [cronic](http://habilis.net/cronic/) which wraps around commands in crontab and does exactly what you want: send emails on errors only.